# GIL in Python 3.1

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

Does anybody knows fate of Global Interpreter Lock in Python 3.1 against C++ multithreading integration

Answer (score 25, accepted):

GIL is still there in CPython 3.1; the [Unladen Swallow](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/) projects aims (among many other performance boosts) to eventually remove it, but it's still a way from its goals, and is working on 2.6 first with the intent of eventually porting to 3.x for whatever x will be current by the time the 2.y version is considered to be done. For now, multiprocessing (instead of threading) remains the way of choice for using multiple cores in CPython (IronPython and Jython are fine too, but they don't support Python 3 currently, nor do they make C++ integration all that easy either;-).

Comment: Thanks, for an answer.
IronPython hopefully has multithread solution since integrated with CLR.

But my task is to plug Python into existing cross-platform C++ application. That is why neither IronPython nor multiprocessing looks good.

Comment: Your C++ application will not be affected by the GIL as long as all entry points from Python into it use the proper macro to allow free threading - only Python's own execution will be serialized (with the GIL being anyway dropped during I/O &c). Ironclad, http://www.resolversystems.com/documentation/index.php/Ironclad.html, offers some (yet-incomplete) help w/IronPython<->C/C++ interfacing, but "multiplatform" is not .NET's strength at this time; and I know of no similar helpers for Jython.

Answer (score 17):

Significant changes will occur in the GIL for Python 3.2. Take a look at the [What's New for Python 3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.2.html#multi-threading), and [the thread that initiated it in the mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-October/093359.html).

While the changes don't signify the end of the GIL, they herald potentially enormous performance gains.

### Update

- The general performance gains with the new GIL in 3.2 by Antoine Pitrou were negligible, and instead focused on [improving contention issues](http://bugs.python.org/issue7316) that arise in certain corner cases.
- An [admirable effort](http://bugs.python.org/issue7946) by David Beazley was made to implement a scheduler to significantly improve performance when CPU and IO bound threads are mixed, which was unfortunately shot down.
- The Unladen Swallow work was [proposed for merging](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3146/) in Python 3.3, but this has been withdrawn due to lack of results in that project. [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) is now the preferred project and is currently [requesting funding](http://pypy.org/py3donate.html) to add Python3k support. There's very little chance that PyPy will become the default at present.

Efforts have been made for the last 15 years to remove the GIL from CPython but for the foreseeable future it is here to stay.

Comment: @Matt Joiner I'm attentively gaze at "Unladen Swallow" (http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/) project. It is only solution in term of my question.

Comment: @Dewfy, I've taken a look at unladen-swallow, and they openly admit they weren't as successful as they hoped. their efforts may be merged into python 3.3 however, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3146/

Comment: let's cross th finger for python 3.3 to be succeeded with multi threading

Answer (score 9):

The GIL will not affect your code which does not use python objects. In Numpy, we release the GIL for computational code (linear algebra calls, etc...), and the underlying code can use multithreading freely (in fact, those are generally 3rd party libraries which do not know anything about python)

Comment: But exactly what I want - to run multiple plugged scripts simultanously. This idea stuck even when two simultanously executed chunk of Python doesn't use common resources.

Answer (score 4):

The GIL is a good thing.

Just make your C++ application release the GIL while it is doing its multithreaded work. Python code will continue to run in the other threads, unspoiled. Only acquire the GIL when you have to touch python objects.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there will always be a GIL.
The reason is performance. Making all the low level access thread safe - means putting a mutex around each hash operation etc. is heavy. Remember that a simple statement like

```
self.foo(self.bar, 3, val)
```

Might already have at least 3 (if val is a global) hashtable lookups at the moment and maybe even much more if the method cache is not hot (depending on the inheritance depth of the class)

It's expensive - that's why Java dropped the idea and introduced hashtables which do not use a monitor call to get rid of its "Java Is Slow" trademark.

Comment: Any information on how Jython and IronPython solve the same problem?

Comment: @Pavel, IronPython uses .Net approach - only explicitly "declared" methods are thread safe, since it is dynamic language (provided by .Net 3.5) there is no difference between .py and C# code.

Comment: @Lothar You example bound to implmentation of GIL, that is why I'm strongly disagree with "Might already have at least 3..." . Alternative, for example, can be apartment model - you starts some instance  of Python in apartment and mix code with C++ as you want. Synchronization is response of programmer. When 2 or more threads needs collaboration you provides these on demand.

Comment: Don't know what an apartment model is i guess you simply mean separated memory space. Yes thats how TCL is doing it but it would be just a different implementation style of the multiprocessing model. For me threads always mean shared memory and therefore you have to share the interpreter instance and python runtime. And the runtime and interpreter have a lot of internal structures that need to be protected. Even if you don't care if you allow a python program to crash the interpreter you need a GIL or some synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it the "brainfuck" scheduler will replace the GIL from python 3.2

[BFS bainfuck scheduler](http://bugs.python.org/issue7946)

Comment: This didn't happen, it was rejected. :(

Answer (score 1):

If the GIL is getting in the way, just use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) module. It spawns new processes but uses the threading model and (most of the) api. In other words, you can do process-based parallelism in a thread-like way.

Comment: it doesn't relates to my question. You are talking from Python developer point of view. My concern is c++ developer point of view